# "as if they mean exactly the same thing" vs "as if they meant exactly the same thing"

Tags: tense

From [Chemguide](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/energetics/lattice.html):

> Lattice enthalpy and lattice energy are commonly used **as if they mean** exactly the same thing - you will often find both terms used within the same textbook article or web site, including on university sites.

Shouldn't it be "as if they meant exactly the same thing", to indicate that in reality they are not the same thing?

Comment: But in the contexts described they **do** mean the same thing!

Comment: @StoneyB - he writes that they are slightly different, although their numerical values are almost identical.

Comment: The author says they're different, but they are treated in the sources as identical, so a non-counterfactual is appropriate in speaking of what the sources say.

Comment: What is the reason to put it in the past tense? "commonly used" indicates present tense to me. Without that, I would leave it as is. For example, "Is that what you *meant*?" is in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as if they **mean** exactly the same thing

is correct, since

> Lattice enthalpy and lattice energy ***are*** commonly used

to move it to the past

> Lattice enthalpy and lattice energy ***were*** commonly used as if they ***meant*** exactly the same thing - *but textbooks nowadays have been update to show the distinction*